# Proof for interchangeable sum and integrals involving Leibniz test

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I would be grateful for some help or hints with this proof.
Let $ \left ( X, \Omega , \mu  \right )  $ be a measure space and $ f_n $ a decreasing sequence of $\mu$-integrable functions, converging pointwise to $0$,
Prove that $ \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}\int f_n = \int \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}f_n $
I have a hint to use Leibniz proof for alternating series

So here is what I've done so far:

For the right-hand side:

Let $ \int \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}f_n = \int S_n $, with $ S_n = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}f_n $

Note that $ f_n\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow \infty]{} 0 $, and
$ f_0 \geq f_1 \geq f_2 \geq f_3 \geq ... \geq $

So we have $f_0 \geq f_0-f_1+f_2\geq f_0-f_1+f_2-f_3+f_4 \geq ...\geq$ and $f_0-f_1 \leq f_0-f_1+f_2-f_3 \leq ... \leq$

Then $S_{2n}$ is monotone increasing and $S_{2n+1}$ is monotone decreasing and note that $S_{2n+1}=S_{2n}+f_{2n+1}\geq S_{2n}$

Note also that $lim_{n \to \infty}(S_{2n+1}-S_{2n})=lim_{n \to \infty}f_{2n+1}=0$ and therefore the sum converges and $S_{2n}<S<S_{2n+1}$
This implies that the $ \int \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}f_n = \int S $ is finite.

We also note that the left-hand side is $\sum_{n \geq 0}(-1)^{n}\int f_n = \int f_0 + \int f_2 + ... + \int(-f_1) + \int(-f_3) +...$ = $\sum_{n \geq 0}\int f_{2n} + \sum_{n \geq 0} \int (-f_{2n+1}) $

I'd like to apply Fubini's theorem that for general $f_n$, if $\int \sum_{n \geq 0}|f_n| < \infty $ or $ \sum_{n \geq 0}\int |f_n| < \infty $ then $ \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}\int f_n = \int \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}f_n $ but Leibniz test isn't enough to prove that $\sum_{n \geq 0}\int |f_n| < \infty$. I'm stuck here and I don't know how to finish. I feel like I'm close either totally wrong. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, not totally wrong. If $S_n$ is defined as
$$S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^kf_k,
$$
then you may have some of your inequalities pointing the wrong direction. I find that the $(S_{2n})$ are monotone decreasing, the $(S_{2n+1})$ are monotone increasing, and that $S_{2n+1}=S_{2n} - f_{2n+1}\le S_{2n}$. Nonetheless, your argument shows that the sequence $(S_n)$ converges pointwise to a limit $S$.

The key to completing the proof is to notice (and prove) that each $S_n$ is non-negative. So now you can use *dominated convergence* to conclude
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int S_n=\int S$$
which is the same as saying
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k \int f_k = \int\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kf_k$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, I somehow forgot about dominated convergence. 
Also realised that my inequalities are in the wrong direction since it's not $ (-1)^{k-1}f_k $ but rather $ (-1)^{k}f_k $ (I think)